# Android: Use onTouch and OnLongClick in my view

Tags: android, class, onclick

I have a problem. It is impossible to use onLongClick in my View an element. I created a certain class and in it there have to be two processings of events of onTouch and onLongClick.

```
public class myClass extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHilder.Callback {
...
//I define my thread and constructor
...
public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent ev) {
...
// here work in touch events
...
return true;
}
```

Now as it is correct to me to declare onLongClick in my class. Also it is desirable that he knew coordinates of a defined event.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but for onlongpress use this:

```
  buttonname.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            //whatever method you want to call

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: this work, but only in onTouch write return super.onTouch(event). But it wouldn't be desirable to cross events. Better that everyone worked in itself.